# Where is timer in a Windows store app?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-store-apps

I could not find the Timer when developing a Windows Store App in c#. What is the alternative /new name/way of use of it?

Comment: What kind of timer are you looking for? .NET provides three types of Timers, each one has its own special uses.

Comment: Now I am looking for an alternative of System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Different timers for different needs. Roughly...

[DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) - When you want work to be executed on the **UI thread**.

[ThreadPoolTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer.aspx) - When you want work to be executed on a **background thread**.

Answer (score 19):

[`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) is what you are looking for

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += DispatcherTimerEventHandler;
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
timer.Start();
```