# how to measure time in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

i'm currently making a Windows Store app (C#) to communicate through Bluetooth with certain device, and i'm looking for a way to measure how long the process is done.

I've seen the same question like : [Where is timer in a Windows store app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772955/where-is-timer-in-a-windows-store-app) , but this is for timer while in my case I just need a time measurer (like `millis()` in Arduino)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stopwatch - Stopwatch uses an highpresission timer if available, othwise DateTime.UtcNow is used

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
PerformWork();
watch.Stop();

Timespan elapsedTime = watch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: does it need any reference beforehand?