# How to write countdown Timer in UWP?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp

May I ask about how to write a countdown timer (Hours, Minutes,Seconds) in UWP ?
I saw a lot of example in stack overflow but it only for Windows Forms.
Thank You.

Comment: There are plenty of samples: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13772955/2681948), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34271100/2681948) and more. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to execute a task when the application is on the foreground you can use [DispatcherTimer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br244250) to do this. 
You can have a look at the examples and know more about them.

Hope this Helps..!

Comment: Write it in code.

Comment: DispatcherTimer would be good, but it is not really accurate compared to for example System.Threading.Timer